# Java circular dependencies

Tags: java, continuous-integration, sonarqube, circular-dependency

Trying to find a tool that can integrate with SonarQube for detecting circular dependencies between classes.

Used to use Sonar (version 4.5.7) for that purpose but [that feature is dropped](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6553) with the new release 5.6.1. In fact it was awesome because I could set a quality gate and be able to break build on circular dependency violations on pull requests. Main purpose of this question is to find a replacement for that feature in SonarQube.

[JDepend](http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html) is nice but outdated. Not sure if it's possible to integrate with SonarQube and break build on new circular dependencies.

I also looked at [HighWheel](https://github.com/hcoles/highwheel) didn't seem to be able to integrate with SonarQube.

I appreciate if you don't mention JDepend or HighWheel in your answers unless you integrated them with SonarQube.

Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity: circular dependencies between classes? packages? libraries?

Comment: Thanks, classes, edited question.

Comment: ASM gives a hint how to monitor class dependencies through byte code analysis: http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial-asm-2.0.html I guess that could easily be turned into what you want

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd just for the record this was exactly how this was implemented in SonarQube before it was dropped.